# compile older c code

Tags: c, windows, legacy-code

I have taken the task of trying to get an older program to run under Vista/Win7.
The code looks like c code, but "strange"

foo.h:

```
int PASCAL WinMain(HANDLE, HANDLE, LPSTR, int);
BOOL InitApplication(HANDLE);
BOOL InitInstance(HANDLE, int);
long CALLBACK __export MainWndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
```

foo.c:

```
int PASCAL WinMain(hInstance, hPrevInstance, lpCmdLine, nCmdShow)
HANDLE hInstance;                /* current instance         */
HANDLE hPrevInstance;            /* previous instance        */
LPSTR lpCmdLine;                 /* command line             */
int nCmdShow;                    /* show-window type (open/icon) */
{
   /* rest of the code follows here */
```

My knowledge of c is limited and this syntax does not look like anything I have ever seen.
The program has been running under WinXP but does not under Vista/Win7 - I suspect 16bit compilation (It *is* that old...)

The code comes with a make-file which states:

```
# Microsoft Visual C++ generated build script - Do not modify
...
```

But neither VS2010, nor gcc seems to be able to compile this code (not the way I tried it, anyways...)
Using VS2010, an empty solution (vc++) the first errors are:

```
error C2061: Syntaxerror: Identifier: 'MainWndProc' in line 4 of foo.h
error C2059: Syntaxerror: ';' in line 4 of foo.h
error C2059: Syntaxerror: 'Type' in line 4 of foo.h
```

Is there an easy way to get this compiled on a Win7/64bit?

Comment: You could tell us the error messages for starters.

Comment: It really depends on the compile errors you are getting and for which compiler the makefile was made for. We need more info to answer this.

Comment: Using dev-c++ I got the code to compile by commenting the first and the last line from foo.h - both functions are (nowadays, obviously) already declared in winbase.h Thanks for the help esp. for pointing out that this is perfectly valid c code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's what is known as K&R style C, which does not use function prototypes. I can't remember if this is still supported in C89 and C99, it certainly isn't legal C++.

Comment: Ah, and he's possibly using a `.cpp` file. That could indeed be it.

Comment: I updated the question to show the header in use and the first error during compilation. This is using a .c file, no .cpp.. ..

Answer (score 0):

Excluding the `PASCAL` item, there's nothing wrong with the code you've pasted... it's an older style of C (and invalid for C++), no longer in favor but still valid.

Get rid of the PASCAL keyword and it will compile... but it'd be better to find the definition of whatever PASCAL did. I would expect it was #define'd to affect the MSVC calling convention of the function.

Comment: using VS2010 and hovering over the PASCAL statement dislays "#define PASCAL __stdcall" so I think this is ok - at least in VS2010...